# How to create and share my bus booking API?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, wcf, rest

I have created a Bus Booking Website www.volvobusesindia.com. I want to share the bus booking form with other sites so that they use our services.

How can do I this using vb.net?

Comment: I just created a introductory blog post talking about how to build a Web API that can evolve http://www.bizcoder.com/index.php/2011/04/11/web-apis-dont-be-a-victim-of-your-success/

Answer (score 0):

Instead of Giving away Form and stuff.. why dont simply create an API and expose it through a WCF Service and handle Bookings That way.

Comment: I dont have any idea of API and WCF how to create these services using ... VB.net and in Visual Studio2008

Answer (score 0):

As Shekar_Pro mentioned, I would create a WCF or RESTful service that allows your users to get your booking information from your site. Here are a few links to get you started:

- [Walkthrough: Creating and Accessing WCF Services](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386386.aspx)
- [A Guide to Designing and Building RESTful Web Services with WCF 3.5](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd203052.aspx)
- [RESTful Services With ASP.NET MVC](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd943053.aspx)
- [Creating RESTful Services Using WCF](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/kaevans/archive/2008/04/03/creating-restful-services-using-wcf.aspx)
- [5 Lifesaving Tips for Creating a WCF RESTful API in .NET 4](http://benjii.me/2010/03/5-lifesaving-tips-for-creating-a-wcf-restful-api-in-net-4/)

Comment: How to create the APi for my site for booking table. ..from : dropdownlist1 to: dropdownlist2 and journeydate: textbox1

these controls m using in my website. ..

Comment: @sumit look at the first link given by @Jason to get started.

Comment: @sumit, You're not going to give the users access to the actual form. WCF and RESTful services give them the ability to access the data *behind* the form. Once you've created the methods that will let users read, update and insert the data themselves, they won't need your form and could even create their own.